# RACSignal doNext with signals

Tags: ios, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

I need to be able to use `doNext` with a signal inside, not just a block. The problem is that I use signals for side effects too.

When I do this kind of things my code looks really messy.

For example:

```
[httpRequestSignal flattenMap:^(Response *response) {
    // Save the response.
    return [[self saveResponse:response] then:^{
        // Return the response.
        return [RACSignal return:response];
    }];
}];
```

I'm tempted to use `first` and make the code look much better, but it looks wrong making a signal synchronous.

```
[httpRequestSignal doNext:^(Response *response) {
    // Save the response.
    [[self saveResponse:response] first];
}];
```

Any advice?

Comment: Why not just use flatten map and return the save response signal, and then in the save response signal have it return the response? That's how I've handled this problem in my networking code at least.

Comment: Hi lightice, thanks for the response! In the approach you mention, does it make sense to have a `save` method to return the data is saving as well. I think is not a good idea because it's a side effect.
Maybe a better solution would be returning the signal that reads, after the one that saves. 
But still I don't think is the best way to handle this kind of situations.

Comment: That's a valid point. Are side effects inherently bad? Another way this could be done is simply to remove the signal from the saving, and just embed it in a GCD block in it's own method. That way instead of waiting for the save, it is started in a `doNext` block on a background thread, and the program continues. (depends on what kind of storage you are using)